# Imagemagick does not set image to exact sizes

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have an image that i want to set to 1024 x 768 and this is the code i am using

```
<?php
function autoRotateImage($image) {
    $orientation = $image->getImageOrientation();

    switch($orientation) {
        case imagick::ORIENTATION_BOTTOMRIGHT: 
            $image->rotateimage("#000", 180); // rotate 180 degrees
            break;

        case imagick::ORIENTATION_RIGHTTOP:
            $image->rotateimage("#000", 90); // rotate 90 degrees CW
            break;

        case imagick::ORIENTATION_LEFTBOTTOM: 
            $image->rotateimage("#000", -90); // rotate 90 degrees CCW
            break;
    }

    // Now that it's auto-rotated, make sure the EXIF data is correct in case the EXIF gets saved with the image!
    $image->setImageOrientation(imagick::ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);
}

$image = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\uncompressed_images\20221016_120159.jpg';
 
// Create new Imagick Object
$imagick = new Imagick($image);
 
// Set the Compression to COMPRESSION_JPEG
$imagick->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
 
// Set the Compression quality
// This is where that compression method imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG is
// used in the program.
$imagick->setImageCompressionQuality(26);
$imagick->thumbnailImage(1024,768);
autoRotateImage($imagick);

// Show the output
$imagick->setformat('jpg');

$imagick->writeImage($image);
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
?>
```

However the output image is always `768 x 1024`  How can i have the resulting to be `1024 x 768`?

How can i also write image to a specific directory in this line `$imagick->writeImage($image);`  i.e output directory

Comment: This happens after autoRotateImage() and turning +-90 degrees, so it seems to be correct. You could do a resize afterwards.

Comment: To write it try `file_put_contents('/path/image.png', $imagick->getImageBlob());`

Answer (score 0):

You should use autoRotateImage to fix any orientation issue first (so now the image is in right orientation) , and then apply thumbnailImage for resizing

So change

```
$imagick->thumbnailImage(1024,768);
autoRotateImage($imagick);
```

to

```
autoRotateImage($imagick);
$imagick->thumbnailImage(1024,768);
```